# Xcode 7.3 taking too much space

Tags: xcode, macos

I have seen that after every Xcode update, the free space of my 128 GB SSD drive has decreased, without my knowing why this is happening. I have read some articles on how to free disk space simply by deleting some unnecessary Xcode files, but they did not do any good on my situation. Just a few days ago, I had 87 GB of free disk space, and an update of Xcode took place. Now my free space is 83.3 GB. My system version is El Capitan Is there any way to reclaim some space?

Comment: The compressed dmgs for Xcode increased by .4 GB between 7.2.1 and 7.3. Why do you believe the new version should not be larger or that your system may now contain "unnecessary" files?

Comment: I don't believe that my system contains unnecessary files at all, but in some articles people giving advice to delete the contents of the device support folder(or other xcode folders) in order to save some disk space, and i did not know what to believe, so i asked here in order to get my answer for someone who knows better, instead of taking negative vote..

Comment: I re installed the whole el capitan and the free space on hard disk raised from 83.3 gb to 100gb with the same applications installed on my mac, so i believe somewhere on the system was saved something like xcode backup..

Comment: TO be honest, I think that having 83G free on a 128G drive is pretty good. The most likely places I know where space goes is things such as Downloads, caches, email, backups and the likes. If you are really concerned about space I would suggest investing in a space analysis program such as DaisyDisk (Which I use and recommend). Then you can see where the space is going and make educated decisions about what you can and cannot delete.

Comment: My free space is about 22 GB. You're much better off than me.